# Copy a product's attributes value to another attribute?

Tags: php, product-attribute, programmatically

I want to copy a product's attribute (weight) to another atribute (general_weight).

I found this:

Create an script at magento root `update.php` and put the below code :

```
<?php
require_once  "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app("admin");
umask();

/*
 Step2: get Product Collection filter by Saleable
*/
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('weight');

foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
$val=$product->getWeight();
/*$product->getWeight() is not given the value then used 

$product->getResource()->getAttribute('weight')->getFrontend()->getValue($product-)

*/
$product->setGeneralWeight($val);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'general_weight');

}
```

then run the script by browser or shell php program.

but this faces to an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getWeight() on a non-object in update.php on line 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
```

with:

```
foreach($collection as $product){
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `foreach` loop looks like this:

```
foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
```

but then you get the weight like this:

```
$val=$product->getWeight();
```

the variable names don't match.

Comment: welcome back @marius..... happy to  see again

Answer (score 2):

There issue with product object name.you should change `$eachproduct` to `$product`t as product object variably name is not match that why this create error